# Were Rhaegar Targaryen and Elia Martell's children ever explicitly named in the show?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the season 7 finale of *Game of Thrones*, we find out that Rhaegar's youngest son's given name at birth is:

> Aegon Targaryen. In the books, we know that was the name given to the male child of Elia and Rhaegar. In the books, he was actually swapped with another baby and snuck away to be raised out of Westeros, and was not killed by the Lannisters when they stormed King's Landing, unknown to almost everyone. That was dropped from the TV show, but I always assumed that the baby who was killed was named Aegon. It seems odd that they'd name two sons of Rhaegar the same name.

Were the names of the other children ever explicitly stated in the show (**not the books**)?

Comment: I believe they may have been when they discuss Robert making the order but I don't have time to go looking right now.

Comment: [Related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/why-are-there-two-characters-named-aegon) on SFF.SE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes!**

> "House Clegane was built upon dead children. I saw them lay Prince Aegon and Princess Rhaenys before the Iron Throne." 
> <sub>*- Thoros of Myr, Season 3 Episode 5 "Kissed by Fire"*</sub>

Comment: This will be the accepted answer, but I don't see a rush.  That name makes no sense to me now. I had assumed it was "Edgar," originally, because of that.

Comment: You are not the only one confused by it... I asked the the "Why/How" over on SFF! That was how I was able to answer this so quickly.

Comment: What does that mean `lay before the Iron Throne`?

Comment: @Skooba Though I appreciate the [sass](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sass), I really just wanted to know what it means. Does it mean their dead bodies?

Comment: @Skooba I was confused whether he meant they brought them forth to the Iron Throne and Gregor killed them there or not, hence the question. +1 for sass, though, gotta have that in order to appreciate good-natured people more.